# Error Opening Project: the R project cannot be open

Tags: r, rstudio, project, proj

When I try to open a R project (.Rproj file), I cannot and this error message appears:

Project 'abc.Rproj' could not be opened. The project file did not include a version attribute (it may have been created by a more recent version of RStudio).

Can anyone help me and tell me how I can fix the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I deleted the `.Rproj` file and then recreated it in the same directory. Problem vanished. I probably lost some cached project information when doing this, but that wasn't a bit deal to me. git data is stored separately outside the `.Rproj` file, so that's good.